# Key DataType for a high volume SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, star-schema, primary-key-design

I in the process of designing a database for high volume data and I was wondering what datatype to use for the primary keys?

There will be table partitioning and the database will ultimatley be clustered and will be hot failover to alternative datacentres.

**EDIT**

---

Tables - think chat system for multiple time periods and multiple things to chat about with multiple users chatting about the time period and thing.

Exponential issues are what I am thinking about - ie something could generate billions of rows in small time period. ie before we could change the database or DBA doing DBA things

Mark - I share your concearn of GUID - I dont like coding with GUIDs flying about.

Comment: What is the expected number of rows in the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With just the little bit of info you've provided, I would recommend using a **BigInt**, which would take you up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, a number you're not likely to ever exceed. (Don't start with an INT and think you can easily change it to a BigInt when you exceed 2 billion rows. Its possible (I've done it), but can take an extremely long time, and involve significant system disruption.)

Kimberly Tripp has an Excellent series of blog articles (*[GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)* and *[The Clustered Index Debate Continues](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)*) on the issue of creating clustered indexes, and choosing the primary key (related issues, but not always exactly the same). Her recommendation is that a clustered index/primary key should be:

1. **Unique** (otherwise useless as a key)
2. **Narrow** (the key is used in all non-clustered indexes, and in foreign-key relationships)
3. **Static** (you don't want to have to change all related records)
4. **Always Increasing** (so new records always get added to the end of the table, and don't have to be inserted in the middle)

If you use a BigInt as an increasing identity as your key and your clustered index, that should satisfy all four of these requirements.

Edit: Kimberly's article I mentioned above (*[GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)*) talks about why a (client generated) GUID is a bad choice for a clustering key:

> But, a GUID that is not sequential -
>   like one that has it's values
>   generated in the client (using .NET)
>   OR generated by the newid() function
>   (in SQL Server) can be a horribly bad
>   choice - primarily because of the
>   fragmentation that it creates in the
>   base table but also because of its
>   size. It's unnecessarily wide (it's 4
>   times wider than an int-based identity
>   - which can give you 2 billion (really, 4 billion) unique rows). And,
>   if you need more than 2 billion you
>   can always go with a bigint (8-byte
>   int) and get 263-1 rows.

SQL has a function called NEWSEQUENTIALID() that allows you to generate sequential GUIDs that avoid the fragmentation issue, but they still have the problem of being unnecessarily wide.

Comment: Hi Brad - thanks for this detailed answer - I will be leaving it open till next week and I hope others vote this up as it answers by question at the moment.  Just wanted to say thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can always go for **int** but taking into account your partitioning/clustering I'd suggest you look into **uniqueidentifier** which will generate globally unique keys.

Answer (score 1):

int tends to be the norm unless you need massive volume of data, and has the advantage of working with `IDENTITY` etc; `Guid` has some advantages if you want the numbers to be un-guessable or exportable, but if you use a `Guid` (unless you generate it yourself as "combed") you should ensure it is non-clustered (the index, that is; not the farm), as it won't be incremental.

Answer (score 0):

I thik that int will be very good for it.

> The range of INTEGER is - 2147483648 to 2147483647.

also you can use UniqueIdentifier (GUID), but in this case

- table row size limit in MSSQL
- storage + memory. Imagine you have tables with 10000000 rows and growing
- flexibility: there are T-SQL operators available for INT like >, <, =, etc...
- GUID is not optimized for ORDER BY/GROUP BY queries and for range queries in general